# How to prevent child from returning select in cursor (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor

I am trying to send one response back to an API from a SQL Server cursor.

The cursor calls a stored procedure that has a select in it.

```
declare db_cursor cursor for select 
[item]
from someTable

open db_cursor;

fetch next from db_cursor into @item

while @@fetch_status = 0 begin  

  exec db..someStoredProcedure @item -- Prevent a select in this proc

  fetch next from db_cursor into @item

end;

close db_cursor;
deallocate db_cursor;

select 'end cursor' -- Send this back to API
```

How can I prevent `exec select` from being returned to the parent procedure so that only `end cursor` is selected once the cursor is complete?

Comment: Don't select? Once you select its getting returned to the client...

Comment: I'm more interested in a command like `prevent default` that I can use without modifying the underlying procedure.

Comment: Pretty sure thats not possible... you could try using the `exec` as an insert to a temp table, that would swallow it.

Comment: What would that pattern look like?

Comment: Sorry in a rush... google "sql exec insert"